# Detect changes of FormArray children

Tags: angular, typescript, formarray

I have a `FormArray` with different `FormControl` items inside it.
I want to be able to listen to the change event of any of them.

I tried to do this:

```
this.form = this.fb.group({
    items: this.fb.array([this.fb.control('')])
});

(<FormArray>this.form.get('items')).controls.forEach((control: FormControl) => {
    control.valueChanges.subscribe(change => console.log(change));
});
```

But I never seem to get to the `console.log`, even though I am sure that the children controls are firing up a change event (from `ControlValueAccessor` interface).

What would be the way to **subscribe to the change of children controls of a `FormArray`**?

Comment: just subscribe to changes on the `FormArray`, if possible. // btw, your current code looks like it SHOULD work - can you post the template here too ?

Comment: You need to check for each control of form array controls. So for example if you have control as items -

    (<FormArray>this.form.get('items')).controls.forEach(
        control => {
          control.get('item').valueChanges
            .debounceTime(100)
            .distinctUntilChanged()
            .subscribe(value => {
              this.onChanges(value);
            });
        }
      );

Comment: I agree with c69 - your code looks like it should work. Check this question and epsilon's answer - it worked for me:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53654938/how-to-identify-which-item-in-formarray-emitted-valuechanges-event

Answer (score 3):

```
 this.form.get('items').valueChanges.subscribe(changes=> {
     console.log(changes)
 })
```

Comment: can you provide stackblitz of your issue?

Comment: This is listening for changes  on 'items' and as I understand the question, Jago needs to listen to all of the controls separately.

Comment: he wants from any of them, this is just an example, he could write form name that he wants to listen, of just  this.form.valueChanges, to listen to overall changes in form

Answer (score 0):

Adding this for anyone who might have found this question on Google.

The main problem with `FormArray` is that its children are dynamic they can be added and removed, so before detecting changes on them we need to detect changes on the `FormArray` itself, but only when new children are added or removed, we can do it with something like this:

```
let length = 0;
let childrenChangesObservable = control.valueChanges.pipe(
    filter(() => control.length != length),
    switchMap(() => {
        length = control.length;
        // Here we can detect changes on the new children
    })
);
```

Now to handle changes on the children the trick here is to ignore the outer observable `childrenChangesObservable`, use it just as a subscription and work inside it with operators like `tap`, and to check on all children controls use `combineLatest`:

```
// Log each time a child control named "id" changes values
let length = 0;
let childrenChangesObservable = control.valueChanges.pipe(
    filter(() => control.length != length),
    switchMap(() => {
        length = control.length;
        return combineLatest(control.controls.map(c => c.controls.id.valueChanges.pipe(
            tap(v => console.log("New value", v))
        )));
    })
);
// We don't care about what comes out of here and when,
// this just handles the subscriptions to the inner observables
childrenChangesObservable.subscribe();
```

This way the operators inside each inner observable are executed when needed but the outer will emit only when all of them emit at least once, but we don't care about that since we are doing our stuff inside

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution that we can use to achieve the valueChanges on formArray.

In this case we are using auto complete field for the State.

```
 // state stuff
 statesList: string[] = [];
 filteredStateOptions: Observable<string[]>[] = [];
```

where we are attaching a formGroup to the formArray we do the following.

```
this.filteredStateOptions[(formarray).length - 1] = this.owners.controls[(formarray).length - 1].get('State').valueChanges
  .pipe(
    distinctUntilChanged(),
    startWith(''),
    map((value: string) => this._filter(value))
  );
```

Added the following for understanding of what happens using _filter

```
// filter needed for States
private _filter(value: string): string[] {
if (!value) { return; }
const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();
return this.statesList.filter(option => option.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue));
}
```

Then in the template

```
        <input matInput spellcheck="false" type="text" formControlName="State" required
          [matAutocomplete]="autoState" maxlength="2" oninput="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase()">
        <mat-autocomplete #autoState="matAutocomplete">
          <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredStateOptions[i] | async" [value]="option">
            {{option}}
          </mat-option>
        </mat-autocomplete>
```

Here we are using material library but the flow would be the same with or without it. Hope this helps.