# Dynamically update form values in a FormArray using valueChanges

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I know that we can use `valueChanges` on a FormArray and view the changes as it is being typed. My question is straight forward: how do I perform the `array.at(i).patchValue` in valueChanges? I would need to know the index of the row where I am keying the value and update `FormControl`s. What I would like to achieve is for e.g. in a calculator, I want to dynamically show the value when I add two numbers without having to click outside of the input field.

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.form = this.fb.group({
    fdnUnitPrice: [''],
    cap_values: this.fb.array([this.fb.group({
      name: '',
      fdnTotalShare: '', 
      fdnVal: '',
    }
    )])
  })
  this.onValChanges();
}

onValChanges(): void {
  this.capValues.valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
    console.log(val.length)
  })
}
```

In my code above, what should be the result is in `fdnVal`, it should show the value when I multiply `fdnUnitPrice` with `fdnTotalShare`. The next row will probably have a different value for `fdnTotalShare`, so `fdnVal` should be different.

Comment: do you have stackblitz for this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to identify which item in FormArray emitted valueChanges event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53654938/how-to-identify-which-item-in-formarray-emitted-valuechanges-event)

Comment: @joyBlanks i did try to use the answer given in that question, but was unable to

Comment: @ng-suhas no sorry

Comment: are you looking for something like this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-dynamic-form-array-5by4ud

Comment: is the unit price editable? You are only subscribing to valuechanges of the formarray, what happens if user edits unit price, or is it not editable?

Comment: @AJT92 i did not think of that. yes it is editable

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would not use `valueChanges` for the formarray, but instead a function which is called on input from the user. As the unit price is also editable, we can use the same function on that. So I would suggest the following:

in template:

```
<input type="number" formControlName="fdnTotalShare" (input)="calculate(cap)"/>
```

where `cap` comes from: `*ngFor="let cap of capValues.controls;">`

and the function:

```ts
calculate(cap) {
  cap.get('fdnVal').setValue(
    this.form.get('fdnUnitPrice').value * cap.get('fdnTotalShare').value 
  )
}
```

Then we would actually listen to `valueChanges` of the unit price form control, where we then iterate the formarray, and for each formgroup call the `calculate` function:

```ts
onValChanges(): void {
  this.form.get('fdnUnitPrice').valueChanges.subscribe((val) => {
    this.capValues.controls.forEach(cap => {
      this.calculate(cap);
    })
  })
}
```

DEMO: **[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vaoim6?file=src/app/app.component.html)**

PS: Remember to unsubscribe to `valuChanges` when component is destroyed!

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning to a single formarray when you have multiple i hope you can capture the index at that moment bind it to your value change functions

```
this.myForm = this.fb.group({
  arr1: this.fb.array([this.fb.group({name: [''],pay: ['']})]),
  arr2: this.fb.array([this.fb.group({name: [''],pay: ['']})])
});

// binding index with array index
Object.keys(this.myForm.controls).forEach((item, index) => {
  this.myForm.controls[item].valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
    this.myForm.controls[item].patchValue([{name:value[0].pay + 'xxx'}], {emitEvent: false, onlySelf: true})
    console.log({index,value})
  });
});
```

Problem on going in an infinite loop. We have to stop valuechanges from firing if updated via code and not by user, we can do that by passing this `{emitEvent: false, onlySelf: true}` as a second argument to patchValue which will not trigger valuechanges.

A stackblitz for your reference https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-dynamic-form-array-5by4ud

Comment: hi i have tried this but got an error `Maximum call stack size exceeded`. I added in `patchValue` after the `subscribe` in `valueChanges`

Comment: patch value will again call valuechanges. what are you trying to do ?? Can you you make conditional pathes if already patched you would know so then dont patch anymore

Comment: i want to dynamically show the value without clicking out of the input box. so as the number changes in `fdnTotalShares`, `fdnVal` should change accordingly too

Comment: ok so you can reset a flag everytime user enters maybe a hidden control and while you patch value look for that control in every row and set it next time if value is set donot patch value that means valuechanges were triggered due to patch, else if value is reset that means user has updated ui

Comment: can you do a stackblitz based on your suggestion?