# Angular Reactive Forms Dynamic Nested Array detecting the change on losting the focus

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Actually i want to detect the changes of input and dropdown field on lostfocus/blur.

constructor Code:

```
constructor(private schemaCreationService: SchemaCreationService, private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.schemaForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      definition :  this.formBuilder.group({
        fieldName: ['', {
          validators: [Validators.required], updateOn: 'blur'}],
        type: ['', Validators.required]
      }, { updateOn: 'blur' })
    });
    this.definition = this.formBuilder.array([]);
  }
```

I'm trying to findout the changes but it's not working

here is the code for detecting the changes

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.schemaForm.addControl('rows', this.definition);
    this.definition.push(this.createItemFormGroup());
     this.onChanges();
  }

get definitionArray() {
  return this.schemaForm.get('rows') as FormArray;
}
```

// here i'm subcribing the changes two ways one is commented but both are not working. please help me anyone to achieve this. If need more details on this please let me know.
onChanges(): void {

```
this.definitionArray.valueChanges.subscribe(values => {
    console.log(values);
  }); 

 /* const control = this.schemaForm.controls.rows as FormArray;
  for (let i = 0; i < control.length; i++) {
          control.controls[i].get('fieldName').valueChanges.subscribe(x => {
            console.log(x);
          });
    } */
 }
```

HTML:

```
  <tr *ngFor="let row of schemaForm.get('rows')?.controls;let index = index;">
                <td>
                <input  type="text"  class="form-control" [formControl]="row.get('fieldName')"/>
                <!--  <div *ngIf="submitted && fieldName.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                      <div *ngIf="fieldName.errors.required">Column Name is required</div>
                  </div>-->
                </td>
                <td>
                  <!-- <input [formControl]="row.get('fieldtype')">-->
                  <select [formControl]="row.get('type')" class="form-control"  name="type" (change)='onDataTypeChange($event.target.value, index)' required>                      
                          <option value="lookup">Lookup</option>
                          <option value="number">Number</option>
                          <option value="string">Text</option>
                          <option value="formula">Formula</option>
                  </select>
                </td>              
                <td>                    
                    <span (click)="onAddRow(index)"> <i class="fa fa-plus-circle icon-plus-color"></i></span>
                    <span (click)="onRemoveRow(index)"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle icon-minus-color"></i></span>
                    <!-- <th scope="col"><button (click)="onAddRow()">Add Columns</button></th>-->
                </td>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just removed the native html form validation required and it works perfectly.

[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zwgcaa)

Comment: Thank you It working fine but it's returning whole array. Actually i wanted to get updated value ( one array value). can you help me on this.

Comment: follow this link there is a good explanation to achieve what you want https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53654938/how-to-identify-which-item-in-formarray-emitted-valuechanges-event